# Capture payment from invoice create and view from admin

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice

I would like to capture payment from invoice create or view from admin dashboard.

So i have tried calling payment method block that is called when order create from admin area but it always say `No payment information required`

So how can i show payment method block on invoice create and invoice view to capture payment from online gateway like creditcard etc...

[This BLock](https://www.screencast.com/t/cSosFJRegji9)